# SqlAlchemy: Querying the length json field having an array

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table with a field of type JSON. The JSON field contains a JSON object with an array. How do I query the length of this array for each row?

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    items = Column(JSON)
```

Example rows in this table:

```
id: 1, items: [2,3,5]
id: 2, items: [2,3,5, 8, 12]
id: 3, items: [2,5]
id: 4, items: []
```

Expected result:

```
1 3
2 5
3 2
4 0
```

Is there something like this:

```
session.query(Post.id, len(Post.items))
```

*Note: The JSON field contains an array of complex objects, I have used integers here only for the purpose of illustration.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a solution

Create a class that extends FunctionElement like this

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FunctionElement
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
class json_array_length(FunctionElement):
    name = 'json_array_len'

@compiles(json_array_length)
def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "json_array_length(%s)" % compiler.process(element.clauses)
```

and use it like this

```
session.query(Post.id, json_array_length(Post.items))
```

Note: this will work on postgres because the function 'json_array_length' is defined in it. If you want this for a different DB that function will need to change.
Refer [http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/compiler.html#further-examples](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel%5f0%5f9/core/compiler.html#further-examples)

Comment: it's crazy that this is what's needed for such a simple concept, but I guess that's the price we pay for abstraction. Also works for `jsonb_array_length`, which is what I needed - much thanks!

Comment: In case of mysql alchemy please change method name to json_length and it is working fine

Comment: I was getting complaints about FunctionElement not being in __all__ so I switched my import to `from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import FunctionElement`

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution, using the `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func` object:

```
session.query(Post.id, func.json_array_length(Post.items))
```

From the documentation:

> func is a special object instance which generates SQL functions based on name-based attributes
>
> ...
>
> Any name can be given to func. If the function name is unknown to SQLAlchemy, it will be rendered exactly as is.

Source: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func