# Get json length of a column in sql alchemy?

Tags: mysql, json

what is the correct way to query JSON_LENGTH(json_column) in sql alchemy for mysql?

I have tried this query but getting error :     (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1305, 'FUNCTION test_db.json_array_length does not exist')

query :

```
self.session.query(func.json_array_length(DbModelName.data)).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

please find this post [SqlAlchemy: Querying the length json field having an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060259/sqlalchemy-querying-the-length-json-field-having-an-array)

for mysql please update method to json_length. Else we will get the above error

this is working fine